# Question about libraries with no code in it

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

So I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15163065) while working the review queue because it appears to be too broad in that it's asking for a working solution to implement infinite scrolling. It mentions two libraries, so it could also be interpreted as a request for a better library to solve the problem. Additionally, because there's no code from the OP's app it's not really possible to provide an infinite scrolling solution that would definitely work in their case.

For the reasons above this question also is yet to be answered.

Comment: It does have an answer now, but yes, I would consider it close worthy as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These usually boil down to decision anxiety. You're looking at investing a way more than trivial amount of time in one of several *possible* ways to accomplish something, and the amount of debt you'll take on if you make the wrong choice tends to weigh heavily.

I ***wish*** we could come up with a way to support these kinds of questions better without a huge investment in what would turn out to be a new content type for the site, but we've yet to figure out how to negate the not-so-great parts of entertaining this. Mostly, these just don't age particularly well, and we still need to come up with some kind of strategy to handle graceful deprecation of highly-scored but out of date information before we could even think too seriously about it.

If you can get the OP to provide an actual use case based on code where the answer could very definitively be "Option (a or b) would be superior because of (reason)", then these tend to be *mostly* okay. But without that, they're just way too broad, and end up just becoming a vote popularity contest that loses a lot of relevancy in a mere 6 to 8 months time.

Definitely the right call in this case.